# Threejs - Load image with textureloader - problem with planegeometry size and scale 1:1

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load images with TextureLoader and I have a big problem. I don't know how I can add images to mesh in scale 1:1 and how I can calculate PlaneGeometry. I want to display the loaded image in its original size without function scaling. It is very important that the image is displayed in its original size without distortions and blurring.

My code:

```js
function init() {

    container = document.getElementById('cad-view');

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

    height = $('.page-footer').offset().top - $('.frame-wrap').offset().top - $('.frame-wrap').outerHeight();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.screen.width / height, 1, 5000 );

    camera.position.z = 1;
    camera.position.x = 100;
    camera.position.y = 0;

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    
    var mapGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1.052, 0.6329);
    
    var imageMap = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: loader.load('mapa.jpg') });
    
    var objectMap = new THREE.Mesh(mapGeometry, imageMap);
    
    console.log(objectMap);
    
    objectMap.position.set(100,0,0);
    scene.add(objectMap);

    objects.push( objectMap );



    controls = new DragControls( [ ... objects ], camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'drag', render );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
    document.addEventListener( 'click', onClick );
    window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown );
    window.addEventListener( 'keyup', onKeyUp );

    render();
}
```

Thank you a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're stretching a square plane with `PlaneGeometry(1.052, 0.6329)`, then you have two options:

1. Resize your original texture in image-editing software so it matches that aspect ratio.
2. Use the `Texture.repeat()` attribute to make the texture scale. You'll have to get your aspect ratio, then use that. I'm not sure of the math, but I think it's something like:

```js
const texture = loader.load('mapa.jpg');

const ratio = 0.6329 / 1.052;
texture.repeat.set(1, ratio);

var imageMap = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
```

[Read more about `texture.repeat` in the docs.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat)

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, but my problem is different. I want load file mapa.jpg in scale 1:1 without resize. In the moment my image is resize and blured :-( I tried get image size and calculate PlaneGeometry but when i get image width and height i have siaze in pixels. How to calculate pixels to threejs units? is this a good solution?